# IIS friendly server

Tags: iis, xampp, wamp

I need to do some projects with Ajax, Javascript, etc. Most of my other work is with ASP .NET so I need to have IIS in my system totally untouched.
The last time I installed XAMPP or WAMP server, those two messed up with IIS and I had to reformat my entire windows 8.1 system to get it all back to default settings.
Can anyone tell me how to install XAMPP or WAMP server without messing up with IIS, or any other server that would be IIS friendly.

Comment: Just set them to run on a different port.

Comment: do you know about any tool that tells which servers are using what ports on the system?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx